# How to ease the merge into sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, oracle10g

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dept;

DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO
    60 HELP DESK      PITTSBURGH
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> SELECT * FROM dept_online;

DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
    20 RESEARCH DEV   DALLAS
    50 ENGINEERING    WEXFORD


SQL> MERGE INTO dept d
 USING (SELECT deptno, dname, loc
        FROM dept_online) o
 ON (d.deptno = o.deptno)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET d.dname = o.dname, d.loc = o.loc
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc)
     VALUES (o.deptno, o.dname, o.loc);
```

See in the above information given, After WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN statement in the insert i have to mention every column, instead of typing every column can i replace it something else.

Comment: Why not, you know what the values are being pushed into which columns and so will all other eyes who will stare at this code

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the column list *INSERT* but not after *VALUES*. The [manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) says:

> If you omit the column list after the INSERT keyword, then the number
>   of columns in the target table must match the number of values in the
>   VALUES clause.

What the manual forgets to mention - and why I would recommend against omitting the column names - is that the order of the expressions after *VALUES* must match the column order in the table's DDL.